# Horizontal scroll frame in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

Hi I have a frame in a canvas. I want to have a button that adds a text box to the frame every time the button is pressed. The text boxes are added to right of the text box before it, and once there are too many text boxes I want to be able to use the scrollbar to view all of them. But for some reason it isn't working.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
from tkinter import ttk

class Tkinter(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, SecondPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1536x864")
        frame.configure(bg='#151B1E')

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, height=400, bg='black', highlightthickness=0, )
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.frame.configure(bg='#151B1E')
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, width=1336, anchor='nw', tags='self.frame')
        self.canvas.place(x=20, y=200, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.9674479167)

        self.editbutton = Button(self, text='Add', command=lambda: self.add())
        self.editbutton.pack()
        self.myscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.myscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        # width is tweaked to account for window borders
        width = event.width - 4
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("self.frame", width=width)

    def add(self):
        self.t = Text(self.frame, bg='#171D1F', fg='white', highlightcolor='#12171A', borderwidth=0, width=40)
        self.t.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=20)
        self.frame.update()  # update frame2 height so it's no longer 0 ( height is 0 when it has just been created )

        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set, scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % self.frame.winfo_width())

class SecondPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = Tkinter()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a minimal reproduced example, all code from ```class StartPage(tk.Frame):``` is relevant

Comment: While the code from `StartPage` is relevant, all of the code related to multiple pages is not relevant. You can directly put `StartPage` inside the root window to simplify the example.

Comment: Ohhh I see, alright I will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're forcing the width of the inner frame to be the width of the canvas. The reason why the frame-in-a-canvas works for scrolling is because the frame is allowed to be larger than the canvas. You need to remove the code that sets the width, or only set it to the width of the canvas if its natural width is less than the width of the canvas.

Here is where you're forcing it to a specific width:

```
self.canvas.create_window(..., width=1336, ...)
```

... and here:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure("self.frame", width=width)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that now!

Comment: i commented out ```self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)``` but it still didnt work, the frame was just stuck

Comment: I've updated my answer to show where you're setting the width.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I will update my code, and get back to you thanks

Comment: I've removed the restrictions, but the scrollbar for some reason isn't working.

Comment: i fixed it by changing ```        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set, scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % self.frame.winfo_width())
 ``` to ```        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set)```

Comment: @coderoftheday: you don't need to reconfigure the `xscrollcommand` in that function. It only needs to be set once when  you create the scrollbar.